# Is there a better way to use handler in UIAlertController (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to use an AlertController to allow the user to return to the main menu, if a certain calculated value is exceeded. I know that using a simple segue will lead to memory problems.  Is there a way to use the popToRootViewController method in this situation instead of simply using a segue? The compiler yells at me (no doubt for good reasons), but gives me no useful suggestions. I know the problem stems from the handler for the Abort Fit action.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if deltaK > 2.25 {

    var helpAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Stop!", message: "Due  to high toricity, the fit should be aborted.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

     helpAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Abort Fit", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)) })

     helpAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(helpAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: The biggest problem here is trying to present a view controller in the midst of `viewDidLoad()`...

Comment: Unwind segues might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to add `[weak self]` to the start of each handler block if you are referencing `self` in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked the unwrapping issue.  Adding [weak self] to the closure triggered the compiler to signal the error.  This code works as intended. nhgrif pointed out a problem with using an Alert with viewDidLoad.  Should I be looking for another way to do this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if deltaK > 2.25 {

        var helpAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Stop!", message: "Due to the high corneal toricity, a toric GP lens may provide better fit, vision, and comfort. Consider using the Empirical GP lens designer from the Main Menu, or use toric GP fitting set.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        helpAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Abort Fit", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { [weak self] action in self!.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true) }))

        helpAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(helpAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```